# Using flyspell in the current org-mode tree

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm trying to write a small lisp function to run flyspell in a single org-mode branch.  I have added this to my .emacs file:

```lisp
(defun flyspell-current-tree()
  (interactive)
  (org-mark-subtree)
  (flyspell-region))

(global-set-key (kbd "S-<f8>") 'flyspell-current-tree)
```

But when running it I get the following error:

```
flyspell-current-tree: Wrong number of arguments
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

You need to provide `beg` and `end` to `flyspell-region` for it to work properly.  The error is coming from that and not actually from your function.

If you include `(point)` and `(mark)` as arguments to `flyspell-region` it will work properly.

```lisp
(defun flyspell-current-tree()
  (interactive)
  (org-mark-subtree)
  (flyspell-region (point) (mark)))
```